# Multiple time series in ggplot2 from xts object

Tags: r, ggplot2, xts

I have an XTS object and I want to plot several time series from it in a ggplot. How do I plot multiple time series in the same plot?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and observe what and how to [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). In case your question is about code, please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've done so far.

Answer (score 5):

Since you don't provide any dataset, I'll exemplify using the `AirPassengers` dataset:

```
library(datasets)
library(xts)
library(ggplot2)
library(broom)
library(magrittr)
ap.xts <- as.xts(AirPassengers)
mseries <- cbind(ap.xts, rollmean(ap.xts,7)) # mseries is a xts object with multiple variables
names(mseries) <- c("Passengers", "MA_Passengers") # names for the series, otherwise the names are '..1' and '..2'
index(mseries) <- as.Date(index(mseries)) # to avoid warnings since ggplot scale don't handle yearmon natively
tidy(mseries) %>% ggplot(aes(x=index,y=value, color=series)) + geom_line()
```

[image: multiple xts in ggplot2]

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to @RubenLaguna's method, you might prefer the neater `autoplot.zoo`:

```
#Borrowing the set-up from RubenLaguna:
library(xts)
library(ggplot2)
ap.xts <- as.xts(AirPassengers)
mseries <- cbind(ap.xts, rollmean(ap.xts,7)) # mseries is a xts object with multiple variables
names(mseries) <- c("Passengers", "MA_Passengers") # names for the series, otherwise the names are '..1' and '..2'
```

Now the simplest thing to do IMO:

```
autoplot.zoo(mseries, facets=NULL)
```

gets the desired graph.